# NSDictionary enumerate second level

Tags: objective-c, nested, nsdictionary

Consider the following NSDictionary:
[image]

When expanded, it looks like this: [image]

I would like to create an NSObject of each of the "features" keys, with "geometry" and "type" as a property, but I can't get my head around the

```
[myDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
```

approach. Isn't there a way to indicate the entrance level by giving a key name?

I DID do a lot of searching around, but none of the stuff I found seemed to be appropriate. I hope you have some patience with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way I would create the feature objects:

```
@interface Feature : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *geometry; //case is important 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *type; //case is important 
@end
```

Then I would use [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Overview.html) to create it. So I need to implement the method `setValue:forUndefinedKey` to avoid crash:

```
@implementation Feature

- (void) setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key{
    NSLog(@"key %@ does not exist", key);
}

@end
```

Then I assume you want an array of feature object:

```
NSMutableArray *featureArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And to fill this array:

```
NSMutableArray *featureArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[dic enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@", key);
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)obj;
        for (NSDictionary *childDic in arr) {
            Feature *f = [[Feature alloc] init];
            [childDic enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull childKey, id  _Nonnull childObj, BOOL * _Nonnull childStop) {
                [f setValue:childObj forKey:childKey];
            }];
            [featureArray addObject:f];
        }
    }
}];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Somehow, all properties of f are NIL. Shouldn't I first set f's values, and THEN add it to the array?

Comment: Yes, you can add feature object after setting the value. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you know the keys that are stored, you could do this:

```
NSMutableArray * pmaMyObjs= [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray* paFeatures= [myDict objectForKey:@"features"];
for(int i= 0; i < paFeatures.count; ++i)
{
    NSDictionary * pdItem= [paFeatures objectAtIndex:i];
    MyObj* pMyObj= [MyObj alloc] initWithGeo:[pdItem objectForKey:@"geometry"] properties:[pdItem objectForKey:@"properties"];
    [pmaMyObjs addObject:pMyObj];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this "initWithGeo:" means

Comment: Oh my bad. You said you wanted to create objects from the data, MyObj was just an example of a subclass of NSObject with initWithGeo being the first parameter label so you could pass in the geometry field.